# Getting 500 Error While Trying to Display Wordpress Thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

whant to display wordpress thumbnail in loop but when i try i always get 500 error and nothing is working. Please can you help me to solve this problem.

```
        public function renderNewsTicker($atts = array(), $content = null)
        {
            // Override default options with the shortcode options
            $atts = array_change_key_case((array)$atts, CASE_LOWER);
            $options = shortcode_atts($this->defaultOptions, $atts);

            // Get the posts
            $postOptions = array(
                'numberposts'   => $options['num_posts'],
                'category'      => 0,
                'orderyby'      => 'date',
                'order'         => 'DESC',
            );
            if (!empty($options['post_cat']))
            {
                $postOptions['category_name'] = $options['post_cat'];
            }
            $posts = get_posts($postOptions);

            // Render the marquee
            if ($options['show_label'] == 'true')
            {
                $content .= '<div class="pjnt-border" style="background-color: '.$options['label_bg_colour'].'; border-color: '.$options['label_bg_colour'].';">';
                $content .= '<div class="pjnt-label" style="color: '.$options['label_text_colour'].'; font-size: '.$options['size'].';">'.$options['label_text'].'</div>';
            }
            $content .= '<div class="pjnt-box" style="background-color: '.$options['ticker_bg_colour'].';">';
            $content .= '<div class="pjnt-content" data-speed="'.$options['speed'].'" style="font-size: '.$options['size'].';">';
            if (count($posts) == 0)
            {
                $content .= $options['no_content_text'];
            }
            else
            {
                $isFirst = true;
                foreach ($posts as $post)
                {
                    if (!$isFirst)
                    {
                        $content .= '<span class="pjnt-spacer"></span>';
                    }
                    $content .= '<a target="'.$options['target'].'" href="'.get_permalink($post).'"><img class="sliderimagetop" src="http://178.128.240.218/images/2018/08/xidasheli-86x64.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">';
                    if ($options['show_excerpt'] == 'true') {
                        $content .= ' - '.get_the_excerpt($post);
                    }
                    $content .= '</a>';
                    $isFirst = false;
                }
            }
            $content .= '</div>'; // end content
            $content .= '</div>'; // end marquee box
            if ($options['show_label'] == 'true')
            {
                $content .= '</div>'; // end border container
            }
            return $content;
        }
    }

    new PjNewsTicker();
}
```

I want to add wordpress thumbnail string here: ';

This is plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/pj-news-ticker/

Plugin developer told me to use "Probably use the function get_the_post_thumbnail($post)." but its not working :(

Comment: Any error on server error log?

Comment: Hi
What happen when you use ** get_the_post_thumbnail($post)** this function

Comment: Thank you for your response, when i use that code site is giving 500 error, also in admin panel is 500 error :(